# Typescript keyword that always refer to the current instance of the class

Tags: typescript, this

it is possible in Typescript to use "this" or something else meaning just "the current instance of the class" like in C# e Java? And not as the usual binding context meaning in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a TypeScript class, using the keyword this actually referring to the current instance of the class. You can see this in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html):

```
class Greeter { 
    greeting: string; 
    constructor(message: string) { 
        this.greeting = message; 
    } 
    greet() { 
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting; 
    } 
} 

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

With static properties in the other hand, you should reference to the static property with the class name (this is alsp an example from the documentation):

```
class Grid { 
    static origin = {x: 0, y: 0};
    calculateDistanceFromOrigin(point: {x: number; y: number;}) { 
        let xDist = (point.x - Grid.origin.x); 
        let yDist = (point.y - Grid.origin.y); 
        return Math.sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist) / this.scale;
    } 
    constructor (public scale: number) { } 
}
```

When passing a function to an event handler, you can use the arrow function syntax that set the context to the current instance:

```
class Greeter {
    constructor(message: string) { 
        handler.addEventListener(this.greet); 
    } 
    greet = () => { 
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting; 
    } 
}
```

Another option is to use the JavaScript​ function `bind` on the passed function with the this keyword as the argument, so that the function will have the context of the instance:

```
class Greeter {
    constructor(message: string) { 
        handler.addEventListener(this.greet.bind(this)); 
    } 
    greet() { 
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting; 
    } 
}
```

You can read more on 'this' [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript).

Comment: The problem occuor when you have an event handler $("button").click(function() { this.callInstanceMethod() });

Comment: When passing a function to an event handler, you can use the arrow function syntax that set the context to the current instance. Another option is to use the JavaScript​ function bind on the passed function with the this keyword as the argument, so that the function will have the context of the instance.

Comment: Do you mean something like that?      $("button").click(() => { this.callInstanceMethod() });

Comment: Yes. I added examples in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much